# Working with excel .xls, Is there an alternate way to do the below?

Tags: java, python, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

[image]

I have an excel sheet where i need to find the SUBTOTAL of visible cells of Dummy 3 and Dummy 4 columns
 whenever i apply filters in Dummy 1 and Dummy 2.

Can anyone please guide me on this? Either a programmatic way or Excel way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a subtotal to apply to visible cells, you have to use the SUBTOTAL function.

Below the rows with data, you would do:

```
SUBTOTAL(9,<range of cells of the column>)
```

9 is the index for ths SUM operation. You will see a list of indexes and their corresponding operation when you type the funciton name and open parenthesis.

Using this function, when you filter, the result of the SUBTOTAL function will be changed taking in account only visible cells.

Here is the reference guide for this function:
[SUBTOTAL function reference guide](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-7B027003-F060-4ADE-9040-E478765B9939)